# Can I rely on self.request in django class-based views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I see code all the time that relies on using an instance variable to get the request, like:

```
class MyView():
    def get(self, request):
        return foo()

    def foo():
        request = self.request
        return bar(request)
```

My question is, can I rely on self.request being set for every view instance? I can't find anything in the documentation that even references this attribute, and while I see it being set in some places in the source I can't tell if it is always being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is set at a fundamental level in Django's generic view base, [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/999fc0687d6b27309e3604602cf996c71b229537/django/views/generic/base.py#L65), which every other kind of view derives from.

You should be perfectly safe accessing the request attribute provided you're inheriting a Django class-based view of some sort.  If you have some `AttributeError`, it's probably because you forgot to inherit from a Django view (as in the example code posted in the question).

Comment: Ah I did forget the inheritance in my example code. It still bothers me that this attribute is basically completely avoided in the docs, but I guess this is as good as it's going to get.